# AJAX code ends up with 'Get #ADRESS# 404'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am a newbie in rails programing, working on my first project.I have a simple rails app, I want to update a page by calling a controller function. Currently I am just trying to call a simple test, but it fails nonetheless. It seems like I am doing all according to some sparse info I could find on SO.

I was experimenting with various route configurations to no avail.

### My code (fragments):

## Routes

```
#routes.rb
  resources :stations do
    get :test, on: :collection
  end
  get '/stations/test' => 'stations#test'
```

## Controller

```
#stations_controller.rb

def test
      puts "Printing from Controller"
      return 346
end
```

## Index

```
#index.html.erb
       Latitude: <input type="number" name="destinationLatitude" id="destinationLatitude"step="0.001" value="52.200022"><br>
 <button type="button" onclick="test(document.getElementById('destinationLatitude').value)"> Find A Test!</button>
.
.
.
  <script type="text/javascript">
function test(destLat){
  new Ajax.Request('/stations/test', {
      method: 'get',
      parameters: {
      // destLat: destLat,
    },
    onSuccess: function (response){
      console.log('@@KAKAC ' + response.responseText)

    }
    });
}
</script>
```

I'd like to finally pass some coordinates and have my backend calculate a route...Though for now I just want the backend to return anything. All help welcome, thanks!

Comment: I recommend you do the getting started tutorial https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html in order to familiarize with Rails conventions, routing ... There are many things in your code that don't fit the Rails conventions and it is good to learn step by step

Comment: Well few things : your test route is defined twice. Your controller test action is not setup to respond asynchronously. If you ping route `stations/test` it will try to render a view called `test.html.erb` in stations folder. You have to use `respond_to` in order to have multiple behaviors. Also you cannot print text in your controller. One good way to debug is to test each bit one by one. For example, if you type `stations/test` in your navbar, do you get an error ? Etc..

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I'll be sure to read that thoroughly !

Comment: @Maxence do you happen to know off the top of your head a good source for learning specifically AJAX in RoR?

Comment: Not really. I am not even good with javascript. Regarding Rails you just need to know what data type to return with `respond_to` also there is this Rails guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add 
dataType: 'json' to your javascript, more info you can read here "http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/"

This Example for your code

```
function test(destLat){
  $.ajax({
        url: '/users/new',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,  
        success: function(data) {
          console.log( data.message )
        }
      });
}
```

In Controller

```
def test
     respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render :json => {
            :status => :ok,
            :message => "Success!",
            :html => "<b>congrats</b>"
        }.to_json
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I am still missing something in the route part since I still get the same error - how can I make the get method point to a controller? Right now it's trying to get db object with id "test"

Comment: Works now, for future readers, you need to use data.responseJSON.message :)